# Is there a way to detect support for blending modes?

Tags: javascript, canvas, cross-browser

I am trying to see if the browser a page is loaded in supports blending modes. For examples, is there a property I can check so that when loaded in a browser like IE, it would return false or undefined, or do I have to do this by checking which browser the user is using.

Blending modes as in canvas blend modes

http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas-blending

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blending modes"?

Comment: Added an edit to clarify. But I mean canvas blend modes
http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas-blending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing for a specified ability in a browser often involves testing if a method or property is null.

```
// Is canvas supported? Test by seeing if HTMLCanvasElement is 'truthy'

var BrowserAllowsCanvas = !!window.HTMLCanvasElement;
```

But Blending is a property assignment rather than a method/property that you can test as null.

To set a blending mode you assign a blend-mode to `context.globalCompositeOperation`

```
context.globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
```

So, perhaps the easiest test for Blending is to try setting `context.globalCompositeOperation` to a valid blending mode and then check if that assignment stuck.

```
function CanvasAllowsBlending(){
    var hasBlending=false;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='multiply';
    var hasBlending=(ctx.globalCompositeOperation=='multiply');
    ctx.restore();
    return(hasBlending);
}
```

**[ Update: New blending modes have been added to canvas -- causing a problem ]**

As @Kaiido says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955992/js-how-to-get-list-of-supported-html-canvas-globalcompositeoperation-types/33956608#33956608), some of the newly added set of blending modes (in some browsers) will falsely indicate support when there really is no support. Therefore, until browsers correct this error, you can apply the compositing and then pixel test to see if it actually took effect.

Comment: That will work in most cases, except in Safari, where some blend modes ("hue", "saturation", "color", "luminosity") will be accepted but not actually supported. [In this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33956608/3702797) you can find a way to really test every globalCompositeOperation mode.

Comment: @Kaiido. Thanks for the update. The new blending modes hadn't been added at the time of my answer so this update is helpful. :-)