# JS: How to get list of supported HTML canvas globalCompositeOperation types

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I want to make a HTML `select` list, with which I can choose which type of `globalCompositeOperation` will be applied when blending two `canvas` elements, like this:

```
<select name="blending-modes" id="blending-modes">
    <option value="source-over">source-over</option>
    <option value="source-in">source-in</option>
    <option value="source-out">source-out</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Is there a way to programatically get list of available `globalCompositeOperation` types as a Javascript object or array, so it could be used to populate `select` element with data, instead of filling it manually? Is this information stored in some native variable?

I do not want to just verify whether or not some blending mode is supported by user's browser, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751619). I want to get a full list of supported `globalCompositeOperation` types in order to chose blending mode in a browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if HTML5 Canvas blend modes are supported in my browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751619/how-to-check-if-html5-canvas-blend-modes-are-supported-in-my-browser)

Comment: If you want a full list, it is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), just loop through it and you'll get the ones the browser does support. I don't think there is a native object containing it. However, There is one bug/caveat, where Safari *(at least 9.0.1)* does accept the `"luminosity"` parameter but doesn't actually seems to support it.

Comment: Yes, I know :) I am asking if it is available as a native Javascript variable. Something like globalCompositeOperation.types or globalCompositeOperation.blendingModes, or globalCompositeOperation.whatever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no native property telling us which are the `globalCompositeOperation` modes that the browser supports.
You'll have to test it by looping through [all spec defined ones](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#canvascompositingandblending), and check if it is still the one you just set :

```js
function getGCOModes() {
  var gCO = ["clear", "copy", "source-over", "destination-over", "source-in", "destination-in", "source-out", "destination-out", "source-atop", "destination-atop", "xor", "lighter", "plus-darker", "plus-lighter", "normal", "multiply", "screen", "overlay", "darken", "color-dodge", "color-burn", "hard-light", "soft-light", "difference", "exclusion", "hue", "saturation", "color", "luminosity", "plus-lighter", "plus-darker"];
  var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  return gCO.filter(function(g) {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = g;
    return ctx.globalCompositeOperation === g;
  });
}

var supportedGCO = getGCOModes();

log.innerHTML = supportedGCO.join(' ');
```

```html
<p id="log"></p>
```

But there is one caveat / bug because Safari <sub>(at least 9.0.1)</sub> does accept the `"hue"`, `"saturation"`, `"color"` and `"luminosity""` modes, but doesn't actually support it...

So here I made a function to test the different modes.
The idea is to draw two 3x3px canvases filled with a solid color onto a third one. The first one is painted in the top-left corner and the second one in the bottom-left, each of them sharing a pixel in the central pixel of the third canvas.

Obviously this is slower than the property check, but you should only need it once per page so performance might not be an issue.

```js
function testGCOModes() {
  // In this object are stored the pixels as they should appear at the 3 positions we'll look : 
  // 0 is an empty pixel
  // 1 is the first pixel drawn
  // 2 is the second pixel drawn
  // 3 is none of the above (blending)
  // We'll look to the central pixel first since it is the most likely to change
  var gCO = {
    // composite modes
    "clear": [0, 1, 0],
    "copy": [2, 0, 2],
    "source-over": [2, 1, 2],
    "destination-over": [1, 1, 2],
    "source-in": [2, 0, 0],
    "destination-in": [1, 0, 0],
    "source-out": [0, 0, 2],
    "destination-out": [0, 1, 0],    
    "source-atop": [2, 1, 0],
    "destination-atop": [1, 0, 2],
    "xor": [0, 1, 2],
    "lighter": [3, 1, 2],
    "plus-darker": [3, 1, 2],
    "plus-lighter": [3, 1, 2],
    // blending modes
    "normal": [2, 1, 2],
    "multiply": [3, 1, 2],
    "screen": [3, 1, 2],
    "overlay": [3, 1, 2],
    "darken": [1, 1, 2],
    "color-dodge": [3, 1, 2],
    "color-burn": [3, 1, 2],
    "hard-light": [3, 1, 2],
    "soft-light": [3, 1, 2],
    "difference": [3, 1, 2],
    "exclusion": [3, 1, 2],
    "hue": [3, 1, 2],
    "saturation": [3, 1, 2],
    "color": [3, 1, 2],
    "luminosity": [3, 1, 2]
  };
  // create two 3*3 canvases that will be used as layers
  var c1 = document.createElement('canvas');
  c1.width = c1.height = 3;
  var c2 = c1.cloneNode(true),
    // the third one will be the tester
    c3 = c1.cloneNode(true),

    ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d'),
    ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d'),
    ctx3 = c3.getContext('2d');
  // fill our canvases with solid colors
  ctx1.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
  ctx2.fillStyle = 'pink';
  ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
  // get the image data of one pixel that will corresponds to the values in gCO's arrays
  var em = [0, 0, 0, 0], // 0 or empty
    d1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data, // 1 
    d2 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data; // 2
  // the positions of the pixels in our imageData 
  // again, start with the central one
  var pos = [16, 0, 32];

  // make an array of all our gCOs
  var keys = Object.keys(gCO);
  return keys.filter(function(g) {
    var i;
    // get the array corresponding to the actual key
    var arr = gCO[g];

    var layer = [];
    // get the correct imageData for each layer we should find
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      switch (arr[i]) {
        case 0:
          layer[i] = em;
          break;
        case 1:
          layer[i] = d1;
          break;
        case 2:
          layer[i] = d2;
          break;
        case 3:
          layer[i] = null;
          break;
      }
    }
    // first reset the canvas
    ctx3.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
    // draw the first layer in the top-left corner
    ctx3.drawImage(c1, -1, -1);
    // set the current gCO
    ctx3.globalCompositeOperation = g;
    // first check the enum is recognized
    if (ctx3.globalCompositeOperation !== g) {
      return false;
    }
    // draw the second layer in the top-right corner so it comes over it
    ctx3.drawImage(c2, 1, 1);
    // get the image data of our test canvas
    var d3 = ctx3.getImageData(0, 0, 3, 3).data;
    // we will first admit that it is supported;
    var tempResult = true;
    // iterate through the 3 positions (center, top-left, bottom-right)
    for (i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
      // we know what it should return
      if (layer[i] !== null) {
        // is it the same pixel as expected ?
        tempResult = d3[pos[i]] === layer[i][0] &&
          d3[pos[i] + 1] === layer[i][1] &&
          d3[pos[i] + 2] === layer[i][2] &&
          d3[pos[i] + 3] === layer[i][3];
      }
      // some blending operation
      else {
        // is it different than the last drawn layer ? 
        //(if the mode is not supported, the default gCO "source-over" will be used)
        tempResult = d3[pos[i]] !== d2[0] || d3[pos[i] + 1] !== d2[1] || d3[pos[i] + 2] !== d2[2] || d3[pos[i] + 3] !== d2[3];
      }
      // our flag switched to false
      if (!tempResult)
      // no need to go to the other pixels, it's not supported
        return false;
    }
    // this mode is supported
    return true;
  });
}
var supportedGCO = testGCOModes();
log.innerHTML = supportedGCO.join(' ');
```

```html
<p id="log"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just converted Kaiido's solution into an js object with a public **test(blendModeName)** method. Maybe it's of use to someone.

```
// based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955992/js-how-to-get-list-of-supported-html-canvas-globalcompositeoperation-types
function BlendModeTester () {
  var ctx1, c1, ctx2, c2, ctx3, c3;
  var pos;
  var em, d1, d2;
  var blendModeDefinition = {
      "source-over": [2, 1, 2],
      "source-in": [2, 0, 0],
      "source-out": [0, 0, 2],
      "source-atop": [2, 1, 0],
      "destination-over": [1, 1, 2],
      "destination-in": [1, 0, 0],
      "destination-out": [0, 1, 0],
      "destination-atop": [1, 0, 2],
      "lighter": [3, 1, 2],
      "copy": [2, 0, 2],
      "xor": [0, 1, 2],
      "multiply": [3, 1, 2],
      "screen": [3, 1, 2],
      "overlay": [3, 1, 2],
      "darken": [1, 1, 2],
      "color-dodge": [3, 1, 2],
      "color-burn": [3, 1, 2],
      "hard-light": [3, 1, 2],
      "soft-light": [3, 1, 2],
      "difference": [3, 1, 2],
      "exclusion": [3, 1, 2],
      "hue": [3, 1, 2],
      "saturation": [3, 1, 2],
      "color": [3, 1, 2],
      "luminosity": [3, 1, 2]
    };

  this.initialize = function () {
    // create two 3*3 canvases that will be used as layers
    c1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    c1.width = c1.height = 3;
    c2 = c1.cloneNode(true);
    // the third one will be the tester
    c3 = c1.cloneNode(true);

    ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d');
    ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');
    ctx3 = c3.getContext('2d');

    // fill our canvases with solid colors
    ctx1.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
    ctx2.fillStyle = 'pink';
    ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 3, 3);

    // get the image data of one pixel that will correspond to the values in the blendModeDefinition array
    em = [0, 0, 0, 0], // 0 or empty
    d1 = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data, // 1
    d2 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data; // 2

    // the positions of the pixels in our imageData
    // again, start with the central one
    pos = [16, 0, 32];
  }

  this.test = function(blendModeName) {
    var i;
    // get the array corresponding to the actual key
    var arr = blendModeDefinition[blendModeName];

    var layer = [];
    // get the correct imageData for each layer we should find
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      switch (arr[i]) {
        case 0:
          layer[i] = em;
          break;
        case 1:
          layer[i] = d1;
          break;
        case 2:
          layer[i] = d2;
          break;
        case 3:
          layer[i] = null;
          break;
      }
    }
    // first reset the canvas
    ctx3.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, 3, 3);
    // draw the first layer in the top-left corner
    ctx3.drawImage(c1, -1, -1);
    // set the current blend mode
    ctx3.globalCompositeOperation = blendModeName;
    // draw the second layer in the top-right corner so it comes over it
    ctx3.drawImage(c2, 1, 1);
    // get the image data of our test canvas
    var d3 = ctx3.getImageData(0, 0, 3, 3).data;
    // we will first admit that it is supported;
    var tempResult = true;
    // iterate through the 3 positions (center, top-left, bottom-right)
    for (i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
      // we know what it should return
      if (layer[i] !== null) {
        // is it the same pixel as expected ?
        tempResult = d3[pos[i]] === layer[i][0] &&
          d3[pos[i] + 1] === layer[i][1] &&
          d3[pos[i] + 2] === layer[i][2] &&
          d3[pos[i] + 3] === layer[i][3];
      }
      // some blending operation
      else {
        // is it different than the last drawn layer ?
        //(if the mode is not supported, the default blend mode "source-over" will be used)
        tempResult = d3[pos[i]] !== d2[0] || d3[pos[i] + 1] !== d2[1] || d3[pos[i] + 2] !== d2[2] || d3[pos[i] + 3] !== d2[3];
      }
      // our flag switched to false
      if (!tempResult)
      // no need to go to the other pixels, it's not supported
        return false;
    }
    // this mode is supported
    return true;
  }
}
```

With this you can test for specific blend modes, instead of testing all at once.

```
var blendModeTester = new BlendModeTester();
blendModeTester.initialize();

if(blendModeTester.test('hue')) { 
  // do stuff 
};
```