# HTML5 canvas apply color to image where shape overlays

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have this image drawn to a HTML5 canvas:

[image: Model]

What I want to do is apply color to just a part of it.
The part where I want to apply color is defined by the following overlay image:

[image: Overlay shape]

So, basically, I would like to guide my coloring by the overlay. So where the overlay pixels meets the main image pixels I should apply a color on the main image. At least that's how I see it working.
Notice that the overlay matches the whole image except for the lacing.

The catch is that I would like to retain the main image texture while applying the color. You can see that it has a leather texture and a "real" feel which I want to keep.

Can you please show me some methods of achieving this or share some thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) is your friend here.

Basically, you draw your overlay, then you set the gCO to 'source-atop' composite mode, which will make all your future drawings to only stay where there were already opaque pixels drawn, so it is important that your overlay has transparent parts.
So then you just fill a rectangle of your desired command, and finally you draw your original image, either behind, or blended to the new shape we just created.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var loaded = 0;
function onload(){
   if(++loaded === 2){
       canvas.width = this.width;
       canvas.height = this.height;
       ctx.font = "40px sans-serif";
       draw();
     }
 }
var original = new Image();
var overlay = new Image();
original.onload = overlay.onload = onload;
original.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIKpI.png';
overlay.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Tre.png';

// list of blending modes.
// Note that destination-over is a composite mode,
//    which place the new drawings behind the already-there ones
var currentMode = 0;
var modes = ['destination-over', 'lighter', 'multiply', 'screen', 'overlay', 'darken',
             'lighten', 'color-dodge', 'color-burn', 'hard-light', 'soft-light', 
             'exclusion', 'hue', 'saturation', 'color', 'luminosity' ];

function draw(){
  // switch between different Blending modes
  var mode = modes[currentMode];
  currentMode = (currentMode+1)%(modes.length);
  // clear previous
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // draw our overlay
  ctx.drawImage(overlay, 0,0);
  // this will keep new drawings only where we already have existing pixels
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // now choose between the list of blending modes
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = mode;
  // draw our original image
  ctx.drawImage(original, 0,0);
  // go back to default
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  // just so we can know which one is shown
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText(mode, 40,40)
  // do it again
  setTimeout(draw, 1000)
  
  }
```

```css
canvas{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Hard-light" seems to be the one that matches my requirements the best. Is there any possibility I could make that work under Internet Explorer? I mean at least for the modern versions. Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: It should work as is for the modern versions. For older ones, blending did not work but compositinf did so you could fallback to compo for olders. I wrote a test somewhere on SO a while back. I can give it to you in about 10 hours (after my sleep) if tou did not find it.

Comment: Not working under Internet Explorer 11 at least. If you can share more details about the compositing you refer to that would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: According to caniuse blend modes are not supported in IE indeed... You can find a test function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955992/js-how-to-get-list-of-supported-html-canvas-globalcompositeoperation-types/33956608#33956608). Then you can fallback to composite one 'destination-over', supported from IE9. With a bit of play on globalAlpha + changing the fillStyle, you might be able to have an acceptable fallback for IE. (Still according to caniuse, edge does support blend modes)

Comment: I ended up using this library: https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender
Although it doesn't bring the same results on "hardlight" mode, it does for the "overlay" mode which seems to be the closest to the requirements. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any hints on how I can apply multiple overlays and color them differently? For example I have a similar overlay for the laces, how would I go about applying the first overlay, then the laces overlay and color them both differently? Thanks!

Comment: @MannyCalavera, The easiest is probably to use off-screen canvases. Do the compositing on separate ones then merge them on the in document one.

Comment: Can you put together an example of 2-3-4 actions of compositing? Would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been really helpful.