# step for making html 5 paint bucket on canvas image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

i want to create an app like https://nerolac.com/paint-colours/colour-palette.html, but i don't know what i have to do.

i've found html5 canvas paint bucket tutorial [here](https://github.com/williammalone/HTML5-Paint-Bucket-Tool) but it isn't what i'm looking for, anyone know the step or tutorial how to create an app like that, i have knowledge about javascript, jquery, html 5

Comment: Your question is definitely too broad for SO, but note that the site you linked too doesn't use a "Paint-bucket" (a.k.a marching-squares). Instead they just do composition from the selected color to the clicked image, just like demonstrated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733430/html5-canvas-apply-color-to-image-where-shape-overlays/41735461#41735461

Comment: wooa thank you , i'm sorry i don't know the keyword haha, but you help me @Kaiido

Answer (score 0):

Easy: Only make copy original image and cut not valid to colorized area (mask) and use globalCompositeOperation with the mask:
    my example :
http://grpd.es/ccolor/mask.html