# Safari Canvas Overlay Blend Mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, safari, blend

Trying to use the `multiply` blend mode on a canvas. In my animate method, I have the following code (React):

`ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'overlay';`

This displays properly in Chrome and Firefox. However, in Safari, the blend mode is not respected and the top graphics appear with no blend mode applied.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Safari:

[image: Safari]

Comment: What version of Safari? [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955992/js-how-to-get-list-of-supported-html-canvas-globalcompositeoperation-types/33956608#33956608) provides a way to test if a blend mode is supported on your browser. Now, on my Safari 11.1.2, both multiply and overlay are supported. If you are using Safari on windows, then you should know that this browser not only is 6 years old (roughly like a IE8 vs Edge), but that it never really approached the experience you could have on any macOs version. All in all, this software is useless. Run a VM instead.

Comment: I'm running Mac OS 10.12 with Safari 11.1.2, having this problem on iOS11 as well.

Comment: Then could you set up a [MCVE] so we can reproduce?